# how to manage multiple sockets at client side in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am creating 20 sockets on the client side application to connect with a server but when my application receives multiple requests so, all the requests go to first sockets.

Please help me to resolve this issue, I want to distribute all the requests to those 20 sockets that I am creating.

Comment: Why you needed 20 sockets? Can you please explain.

Comment: If you wanna distribute/balance the load, you can just turn to `BlockingQueue` or `ExecutorService` to do the work.

Comment: @Dharmraj, 20 is just an example, my application receives thousands of request per second, one socket cannot handle these requests so I need to create multiple sockets.

Comment: @Hearen, I am using ExecutorService to do this

Comment: Please show some code?

Comment: Thanks Inder for explanation, If you are connected with multiple socket with server, Then you can write logic over server to distribute requests to all connected sockets. From client side you can't ensure and distribute the request among all sockets.
OR I would recommend use one socket connection and create multiple worker threads to process the request. Use request pooling as well,  as said by @Hearen.

Comment: @Dharmraj, I am creating ThreadPool of 20 workerThreads  "ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);" and its working fine with almost 1000 request per second but when my application receiving more than 1000 requests in 1 second so my application stops responding and  than  I need to restart the service.

Comment: Is this really necessary? If so, please start from `Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz` and learn how to **optimize** your program.

Comment: If system getting choked, Then you really need to monitor system statsd, CPU utilization and memory uses, and make a proper tuning of your system and worker threads. Also, optimize your code to process a request, It should not be enormous otherwise more requests will be in the waiting queue that will also create a problem.